# single page redirect 301 not working according to the rules in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-alias

```
redirect 301 /Produkte/Supplements http://xxx.xx/Produkte/Inhaltsstoffe/Proteine
```

why does this rule also redirects

```
 /Produkte/Supplements/xyz
```

to

```
http://xxx.xx/Produkte/Inhaltsstoffe/Proteine/xyz
```

?

can't get my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

Due to [apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) - If the client requests `http://example.com/Produkte/Supplements/xyz` , it will be told to access `http://xxx.xx/Produkte/Inhaltsstoffe/Proteine/xyz` instead. This also includes requests with GET parameters.

To workaround this use more complex `RedirectMatch` rule like so:

```
RedirectMatch ^\/Produkte\/Supplements$ http://xxx.xx/Produkte/Inhaltsstoffe/Proteine
```